# Azure DataFactory Foreach Copy Upsert, howto use key column

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using azure data factory to copy a table from a mysql source to a sql server destination. I'm using the default 'record' functionality. In the copy step, I want to enable **upsert**. I then need to enter the key columns, and I'm wondering how to make sure that each table can have its own key column(s).

[image: See image here]

[image: And key column definition]

Tried entering column names, however the end result looks confusing, what is the key then for which table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to give the key columns dynamically, in lookup table, a field called **key_column** is added for every table_name. Below is the detailed approach.

- Lookup table is taken with fileds table name and key column. In ADF, lookup activity dataset is taken with the lookup table.

[image]

- In for-each activity, lookup table output is taken.

[image]

- Copy activity is taken in for-each activity.  Source dataset is taken like below image.

[image]

- In sink dataset, write behaviour is given as 'upsert' and key columns is given dynamically as
  `@array(item().key_column`

[image]

- By this way key columns can be assigned dynamically and upsert can be performed in copy activity

Comment: How about if a table has multiple PKs?

Comment: In lookup table, you can store all PKs field in the `Keycolumn` of lookup table. Then In copy activity-> sink settings-> Key Columns, you can give the dynamic expression `@array(split(item().key_column),','))`.